# JS file injection in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpmodule, javascript-injection

I need to inject an external javascript file without touching any existing files on asp.net MVC website.

The approach I want to follow is

1. Write a http module as a standalone dll and deploy it to the website
2. Enable the http module using additional web.config file
3. Through the http module inject a reference to a javascript file

How can I achieve this?

I cannot modify existing file to add the javascript. Neither can I modify the global.asax.

Any inputs?